# Can "the direction across" be shortened to "the across-direction"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

This is a question about word merging in English.

The diagonal in a rectangle is in other words **the length or direction across** the rectangle.

Can

> the direction across

be rewritten as one of these:

> the across-direction
>
> the cross-direction

or similar?

Comment: _Direction_ doesn't mean _a diagonal line across something_, so no, it doesn't make sense to use those words as a substitute.

Comment: What @KateBunting said is correct. The diagonal of the rectangle doesn't represent the direction across it. The suggestions provided for the word merger though sounds quite silly. However there is this word, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cross%20direction which exists.